# Moving Message/Log View Below PDF Preview -TexStudio

Tags: texstudio

Although I searched for past questions on how to arrange the layout of TexStudio UI, I did not manage to find an answer to my question.

I want to move the "Message/Log View" interface element below the PDF preview.

Currently I have the following layout:

```
Editor             | PDF Preview
Editor             | PDF Preview
Editor             | PDF Preview
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~| PDF Preview
Message/Log File   | PDF Preview
```

Here is the layout that I want to have:

```
Editor             | PDF Preview
Editor             | PDF Preview
Editor             | PDF Preview
Editor             |~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Editor             | Message/Log File
```

I know that the log part does not show its face unless there is a compilation error; yet, I want to have that kind of interface layout.

Here is my TexStudio information:

```
TeXstudio 2.12.14 (git n/a)
Using Qt Version 5.9.5, compiled with Qt 5.9.5 R
```

OS:

```
Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is NO
I does not appear to be currently possible

I have tested many different combinations of split and merged areas in TeXstudio but there are some  fixed behaviours

The viewer area (either right imbedded or floating)
The Annotation pane is (not always but) most often fixed to the lower edge

The editor area (central)
The Upper pane can be split EITHER horizontally or vertically
The Lower tabbed pane cannot be moved it is fixed to the lower edge

You will need to see if there is an answer or raise a feature request [here](https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+)